# tracing of sql in yii-1.1.14 app

Tags: php, yii, trace

for tracing of sql in my yii-1.1.14 app I wrote in config file :

```
'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'trace',
                'categories'=>'system.db.*',
                'logFile'=>'sql.log',
            ),
    ),
  ),
```

But in in my sql.log file I see rows:

```
2014/02/19 11:39:14 [trace] [system.db.ar.CActiveRecord] Tour.findAll()
2014/02/19 11:39:14 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM `tbl_tour` `t` WHERE (feature=:ycp2) AND (status=:ycp3) LIMIT 10
```

What I need that is to see real values but not parameters like :`ycp3`

If there is any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

you must enable **enableParamLogging** in db connection:

a very good tutorial is here:

http://www.larryullman.com/2013/09/23/debugging-database-operations-in-yii/